# Update Data in mdb Table

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm still working at my first database / time tracking solution.

Right now I can create a new user and a table with the Name of the user and the columns

```
[ID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[Datum] Text, 
[Beginn] Text, 
[Ende] Text, 
[Pause] Text, 
[Arbeitszeit] Text
```

For the next step I inserted new data into the table by using:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into " + user + " (Date, Begin, End, Pause, Worktime) values ('" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + Begin + "', '" + End + "', '" + Pause + "', '"+ Worktime+"')";
```

Begin, End, Pause and Worktime were declared beforehand as strings. That works perfectly fine so far.

But now I'm trying to update/Change the values of the inserted Data and it's not really working.

I'm using the following code right now:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Begin", Begin);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", End);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pause", Pause);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Worktime", Worktime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

command.Connection = con;
command.CommandText = "update" + user + " set [Date] =@Date [Text], [Begin] =@Begin [Text], [End] =@End [Text], [Pause] =@Pause [Text], [Worktime] =@Worktime [Text] where ID = @ID;";

con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The error I am getting is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14) illegal SQL-Instruction;
>   'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'SELECT', 'PROCEDURE' or 'UPDATE' expected.

The error occurs on the line

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If anyone could help me with this I'd be really glad.

Comment: What do you try to do with `set [Date] =@Date [Text]` exactly? What is this `[Text]` for? It doesn't seems a valid sql syntax. And learn parameterized queries and what is `using` statement for.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Clearly, `Datum`, `Beginn` and `Ende`  should be DATE or DATETIME data types - **not** strings!

Comment: @Marc_s i tried using DateTime but i'm taking Begin and End from two separate datetimepickers (one for the hours and one for minutes). Then combining them to a string containing HH:mm. 
It was the "easiest" way for me without getting too much Errors in saving the data into the db and taking it out again.

Comment: @Soner Gönül - The [Text] was actually a copy paste error by me....thanks for mentioning. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing blank space after update , change to this :

```
command.CommandText = "update " + user + " set [Date] =@Date [Text], [Begin] =@Begin [Text], [End] =@End [Text], [Pause] =@Pause [Text], [Worktime] =@Worktime [Text] where ID = @ID;";
```

Comment: @scitch you should accept the answer if it solves your issue .

Comment: i did. But it will only Show if i get more Reputation Points...which is a bit silly IMHO.

Comment: @scitch accepting an answer is different than up voting an answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: oh well thanks for mentioning. As you can maybe tell i'm pretty new in here. :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
command.CommandText = "update" + user + " set [Date] =@Date [Text], [Begin] =@Begin [Text], [End] =@End [Text], [Pause] =@Pause [Text], [Worktime] =@Worktime [Text] where ID = @ID;";
```

try this

```
command.CommandText = "update " + user + " set [Date] =@Date [Text], [Begin] =@Begin [Text], [End] =@End [Text], [Pause] =@Pause [Text], [Worktime] =@Worktime [Text] where ID = @ID";
```